# read_csv zip file > That compression method is not supported [pandas]

Tags: pandas

when I trying to read CSV zip file with python 3.8.5

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\raf\one_may.zip',sep=';',compression='zip')
```

I get  error : That compression method is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can try to leave the defaut parameter `compression='infer'` to detect the compression. It is possible that the compression is not "zip", it can also be ‘gzip’, ‘bz2’, ‘zip’, ‘xz’ (cf. [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation).

The alternative is that your archive is in fact invalid.

Comment: thank you.  I have zip file for sure.   what do you mean "archive is in fact invalid"  ?

Comment: It could be corrupted or not a zip at all. What is that origin of the zip? The thing with zip is that the format is not really standardized, so you could also have a weird custom version. Can you unzip it with another tool? Have you tried to unzip/rezip?

Comment: with winrar its unzip perfect

Answer (score 0):

the problam was that the file was rar and not zip(the defult is rar).

when I compresed again to zip it worked good

[image: winrar]